# PIC24H POT input to control LED blink delay not linear

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, potentiometer

Hello I'm using the PIC24H microprocessor and I wrote a simple program that takes input from a POT using analog input which is then set to a modulus value of delay. It does seem to set the delay, but progression from left to right is seemingly random and inconsistent. Help would be awesome! Thank you!

```
int main (void){
    AD1CON1bits.ADON=0;
    AD1CON1=0x00E0;
    AD1CON1bits.AD12B=1;
    AD1CON3=0x8000;
    AD1CON2=0x8000;
    AD1CHS0=0x0000;
    AD1CON1bits.ADON=1;

    int wtdState;
    int delay;
    int temp;

// Set Analog Input Pin
    _CN2PUE=0;
    _TRISA0=1;
    _PCFG0=0;

//Set Digital Output Pins
    _ODCB15=0;
    _TRISB15=0;
    _LATB15=0;

    _ODCB14=0;
    _TRISB14=0;
    _LATB14=1;

    while(1){

    wtdState = _SWDTEN;
    _SWDTEN=1;
    AD1CON1bits.SAMP=1;
    Nop();
    while(!AD1CON1bits.DONE){}

    _SWDTEN = wtdState;

    temp = ADC1BUF0;
    delay = temp%225+25;

    __delay_ms(delay);
    _LATB15=1;
    __delay_ms(delay);
    _LATB15=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say in the body of the question that the pot readings are *"random and inconsistent"*. On the other hand in the title you comment that the behavior is not linear. This seems like a mixed message......but none the less please consider:

Not all potentiometers are linear. Those used for audio controls are often setup with a resistance value that varies by a log scale according to the knob position. This may be what you are seeing.

Comment: It's a linear POT, but when I sweep the POT the delay isn't gradually changing.  It's kinda random.  I fixed it anyways!  It was the % (mod).  I'm using division to limit the domain/range!

Comment: Well, random isn't linear, right? :)